# jquery mouseover event works partially when trying to implement a tooltip for fullcalendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, tipped

I am using jquery fullcalendar plugin and also Tipped.js to create tool tips.
Whenever the mouse is entering an event in the calendar, I want to display a tooltip with some extra details about the event.
The tooltip works, but the thing is that it works partially, i.e entering the event with a mouse over doesn't always work, sometimes I need to mouseover it again. it also doesn't work when moving fast from one event to another, it works only when I do it very slow.

Also need to mention that the details for the tooltip are coming from an ajax request (some DB queries are involved) so this might be what causing it to work slow.

here's my code :

```
    $("#tblSpincal td").on("mouseover", function () {

    var me = $(this);
    if (me.attr("dataid") != undefined) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Scheduler.aspx/GetToolTip',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ "dataid": me.attr("dataid") }),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (response) {
                var data = response.d;

                var tooltip = createtoolTip(data.IQCNum, data.Phone, data.Fax, data.NumOfEmloyees, data.Status, data.ActivityType, data.AllDetails, data.ActText, data.Address);
                Tipped.create(me, tooltip);

            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                alert("error retrieving toolTip")
            }
        });

    }
});
```

where 'createtoolTip' function returns a string of some html that will be injected into the tooltip.

I will also consider using another type of events/js libs if it will make it faster, please do post any advise on how may I make it work faster.

Comment: It's probably a bit inconsistent because of the time required to make an ajax request (which remember is asynchronous) and get the response. Sometimes you'll have moused out again before the request can complete. It might be better to use a popover that responds to a "click" on the event, then you can show a "loading" indicator somewhere suitable, and the user knows to wait, also it's not vulnerable to them mousing out (instead they have to click somewhere to dismiss the popover). And/Or consider pre-loading this data somewhere hidden on the page where you can retrieve it instead of using ajax

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I need to use the tooltip with mouseover/enter because it already does something else hen clicking a calendar event.

Comment: then I suggest you need to pre-load the data into the page somehow to avoid the ajax lag. Or, the mouseover triggers a "loading" icon to appear somewhere, and then the tooltip is only shown once the ajax call has finished. You either need to remove the lag, or encourage the user to wait.